# Extract parameter after fitting from Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, root-framework

I am a bit confused in the Poisson distribution. Actually I am fitting a Poisson type distribution[image: Poission type distribution] and the I need to extract its mean and error on mean. So as we know the Poisson distribution  is
[image]

In root (C/c++ based analysis framework) I defined  this function like below

```
function = ( [0]  * Power( [1] / [2]  ,  x/[2] )  * exp (-[1]/[2]) ) /     Gamma(x/[2] + 1)

Where : [0] = Normalizing parameter
        [1] / [2] -> mean (mu) 
        x / [2] -> x
        Gamma( x / [2] + 1 ) = factorial (x / [2])
```

So, In principle then mean of Poisson distribution is mu = [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJhGa.png)/[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF0JR.png)   and error will be the standard deviation which is square root of mean.

But, If I am using this value then my mean is coming around 10 and hence error is ~3.

While the mean of distribution is around 2 (as we can see) so I am confused. Because the parameter [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJhGa.png) 's value is coming out to around 2 or 3. So, should I use parameter [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJhGa.png) as mean value or what??

Please suggest what should I use and why?

My Full code is below:

```
TH1F *hClusterSize = new TH1F("hClusterSize","Cluster size for GE1/1", 10,0.,10.);
    tmpTree->Draw("g1ycl.ngeoch>>hClusterSize","g1ycl@.GetEntries()==1 && g1xcl@.GetEntries()==1");
    hClusterSize->GetXaxis()->SetTitle("Cluster Size");
    hClusterSize->GetYaxis()->SetTitle("#Entries");
    TF1 *f1 = new TF1("f1","[0]*TMath::Power(([1]/[2]),(x/[2]))*(TMath::Exp(-([1]/[2])))/TMath::Gamma((x/[2])+1)", 0, 10); 
    f1->SetParameters(hClusterSize->GetMaximum(), hClusterSize->GetMean(), 1); 
    hClusterSize->Fit("f1"); // Use option "R" = fit between "xmin" and "xmax" of the "f1"
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code how you define the function, not just the string? Why do you have 3 parameters (a Poisson has one parameter plus one for the normalisation)? Have you considered using `TMath::Poisson`?

Comment: with only 1 parameter it is not fitting well my distribution. So If I just do a variable change to introduce 1 more parameter as I said then it fits well. change of variable: x -> x/par2 mean -> par1/par2.
Also, I added part of code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

On the root command line fitting a poisson distribution can be done like this:

```
TF1* func = new TF1("mypoi","[0]*TMath::Poisson(x,[1])",0,20)                          
func->SetParameter(0,5000) // set starting values                                      
func->SetParameter(1,2.) // set starting values                                        
func->SetParName(0,"Normalisation")
func->SetParName(1,"#mu")
TH1F* hist = new TH1F("hist","hist",20,-0.5,19.5)  
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5000 ; i++) { hist->Fill(gRandom->Poisson(3.5)); }
hist->Draw()        
hist->Fit(func)
```

Note that that bin centers are shifted wrt your initial post, such that the bin 
center of 0 counts is at 0 and not at 0.5 (and the same for all the other bins).

Comment: Thanks. 
But, with only 1 parameter it is not fitting well my distribution. So If I just do a variable change to introduce 1 more parameter as I said then it fits well.

change of variable: x -> x/par2
                               mean -> par1/par2

Comment: Hi, do you have any more suggestation?